# == and Equals. Why the complexity?

Tags: c#

With `==` operator I can do this:

```
int a = 10;
int b = 10;
a==b //true
```

In this case C# makes a compile-time decision, and no virtual behavior comes into play.

But, if I use:

```
object a = 10;
object b = 10;
a == b //false
```

The result is false because `object` is a class (reference type)  and `a` and `b` each refer to different boxed objects on the heap.

To solve it I should do:

```
object a = 10;
object b = 10;
a.Equals (b) // True
```

Because `Equals` is a virtual method and it is resolved at runtime depending of the objects’s actual type.

My question is:

**Why the designers of C# didn’t avoid the problem by making == virtual, and so functionally identical to Equals?**

Answer (score 12):

Because `==` is a `static` method, so cannot be virtual. This was probably done to better handle `null`.

Note that your dilemma has nothing to do with boxing, C# uses the compile time type of both parameters to determine what overload* of `==` makes sense. For instance, take the following example.

```
object s1 = "Hello";
object s2 = new String('H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o');
s1 == s2; //False
(string)s1 == (string)s2; //True
```

* Overload is not absolutely correct, since we are searching more than one class hierarchy, but it is close enough semantically for the discussion.

Comment: Exactly, it's not supposed to differ based on order and so must be `static`.

Answer (score 2):

One reason I can think of: because making == virtual of any kind will lead to significantly less predictable behavior with inherited classes.

```
class Base {
  public int First;
}

class Derived {
  public int Last;
}

var me = Base{ First = "Alexei" };
var someone = Derived { First = "Alexei", Last = "Unknown" };
```

Now if some sort of "==" is virtual in base class and not overridden in derived class than `me == someone` is true which is surprising.

Also don't forget that C# is not the only language that compiles code for .Net runtime, so behavior should be reasonable for other languages which may have different syntax features for similar concepts.

Answer (score 1):

Because then it's much more difficult to determine if `a` and `b` are in fact the same object. We might want to know that. We're particularly likely to want to know that if we are dealing with them through variables of type `object`. Identity is one of the meaningful features of an `object` qua `object`. Other definitions of equality are not.

With reference types, we start with both `==`, `Equals` and `GetHashCode` referring only to identity. `ReferenceEquals` always refers only to identity.

When we're very likely to care about some other way of considering two objects of a type to be equivalent, we override `Equals` to make use of it, and `GetHashCode` to correspond.

When we're mostly unlikely to care about identity, we override `==` too. (example: `string`).

With value types, we start with both `==`, `Equals` and `GetHashCode` referring to a field-by-field comparison, because that's the most discriminating view of equality that makes any logical sense with value types.

When dealing with `object` variables, there's both a good chance that we care about identity - so we have `==` and a good chance that we care about `Equals` so we have that. It's hard to think of anything that wouldn't just get in the way.